# Parsing xml files with XMLReader PHP using cache

Tags: php, caching, serialization, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I need to parse several XML files by using XMLReader of PHP. The overall parsed result need to be stored in memory with an array. Therefore the array will contain the result of each file.

What I also need to do is using a caching mechanism (with serialization). I was thinking something like this:

1. I parse the xml file
2. If the xml file is not in cache, I save the parsed result of the xml file in cache (with serialization)
3. If the file is in cache, I need to get the content of it

How can I achieve this last point? I do not want to deserialize the file in order to load the result in memory and save it in the array.

The final output should me something like this:

File 1 parsed result:

```
$result['archive']='archive/';
$result['color']='yellow';
$result['house/height']='200';
```

File 2 parsed result:

```
$result['house/width']='100';
$result['trial']='true';
```

Final result:

```
$result['archive']='archive/';
$result['color']='yellow';
$result['house/height']='200';
$result['house/width']='100';
$result['trial']='true';
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I imaging that _how_ you do it will depend on _what_ you use for caching. Have you done any research into this? If you're just brainstorming, then it's really a little early in the process to be asking a question here.

Comment: perhaps look at Memcache or Redis for your cache engine. There are many php connectors to these two cache engines..